# figure not showing up

Tags: captions

I have this code below, which is the MWE. Just use any image for ex.png

I have 2 questions:

How can I add captions with automatic numbering because I cannot get it to work?

How can I have the figures float around rather than me manually placing them?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{newspaper}


\date{\today}
\currentvolume{1}
\currentissue{3}

%% [LianTze] The newspaper package also provides 
%% these commands to set various metadata:

%% The banner headline on the first page
%%   (The colon after s: is to get a more
%%   modern majuscule s in this font instead of 
%%   the medieval tall s. For anyone interested 
%%   in the history: 
%%  http://medievalwriting.50megs.com/scripts/letters/historys.htm)
\SetPaperName{The Report}

%% The name used in the running header after
%% the first page
\SetHeaderName{The Report}

%% and also...
\SetPaperLocation{\raisebox{-0.5\height}}
\SetPaperSlogan{``example''}
\SetPaperPrice{4\%}


% [LianTze] times (the package not the font) is rather outdated now; use newtx (see later)
% \usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{picinpar}
%uasage of picinpar:
%\begin{window}[1,l,\includegraphics{},caption]xxxxx\end{window}


%% [LianTze] Contains some modifications
\usepackage{newspaper-mod}
%%... so now you can redefine the headline and byline style if you want to.
%% These can be issued just before any
%% byline or headline in the paper, to
%% individually style each article
%%
% \renewcommand{\headlinestyle}{\itshape\Large\lsstyle}
% \renewcommand{\bylinestyle}{\bfseries\Large\raggedright}


%%%%%%%%%  Front matter   %%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{multicols}{2}

\byline{Abstract}{A.D}


\lipsum[1-3]



\headline{ex}




\begin{window}[2,r,\includegraphics[width=3.5in]
{ex.png},\centering{Fig. 1: Example.}]  
\end{window}





\closearticle

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This might be hard to answer without more context, can you make a complete, minimal example that demonstrates the problem? `figure` is of course usually a float, so where it's placed in document doesn't have to be the same as its place in the code, but you are perhaps aware of that.

Comment: Off-topic: Since you're setting `width=1.0\textwidth`, the `\centering` instruction is redundant.

Comment: Please clarify what "not showing up" and "[does] not work" entails. E.g., does the `figure` environment show up later on in the document, or maybe at the very end?

Comment: `figure` is defined in the standard classes, and most other classes, but `window` isn't defined in any standard class or package, so without any information about its definition or what error you got, it is impossible to say anything.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.@Mico @DavidCarlisle I added more code at the beginning to show how I set the document up. The figure using \begin{figure} just does not show up at all.

Comment: It says I can't use a float in multicol environment? Also how do I turn on automatic numbering? I tried using \caption but it does not seem to work.

Comment: @JacksonHart As it was already told you: Add an MWE.

Comment: @Jan Done, please check question again

Comment: Can Latex really not be used to obtain single column figures with automatic numbering?